# Sqldf produce "NULL" using delete statement

Tags: r, sqldf

first i used select statment to retrieve rows for people who have age >=100 using this code

```
b <- sqldf('select * from newdata where age >=100')
Loading required package: tcltk
b
  age          job marital education default balance housing loan  contact day
1 150 entrepreneur  single  tertiary     yes    1136     yes   no cellular   3
2 130 entrepreneur  single  tertiary     yes    1136     yes   no cellular   3
  month duration campaign pdays previous poutcome   y
1   apr      345        2   249        7    other  no
2   apr      345        2   249        7    other yes
```

now when i used delete statment to remove these rows it gives me "NULL" and when i checked the data i found that these rows are still in there not removed yet!!

```
s <- sqldf('delete from newdata where age >= 100')
s
NULL
```

any help please .

Comment: @limo - also not familiar with package but I believe its main intention is manipulating dataframes using SQL where tables would be dataframes (similar to SAS' proc sql). Rather, OP should filter out records not needed: `s <- sqldf('select * from newdata where age <= 99')`.

Comment: The `delete` command does not return anything.  You need `sqldf(c("delete...", "select * from newdata"))` to actually return something . See FAQ#8 on the sqldf github page where this is discussed in relation to `update` which works the same way: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update

Comment: Thanks for your comments , @ G. Grothendieck it works thank you .